# Yahoo Groups doesn't know that my Yahoo account (made from Gmail) is a member of a group

Tags: yahoo-groups

I am a member of a Yahoo Groups account, but with a Gmail account. I can post (via email) to the group and receive email. When I go to the web interface for the group, it doesn't think I'm logged on. I'd like to look at old emails, which I presume I can do in the web interface.

I didn't have a Yahoo account, so I created one today, but I have used my Gmail email address, and I created an account. However the group web interface still acts like I'm not a member of the group. How can I get Yahoo Groups to recognise that I'm a member?